# How i can stop my parrot bad habbit to not cut my shoes or sandal stone?

Tags: training, parrots

How i can stop my parrot bad habbit to not cut my shoes or sandal stones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the nature of most parrots to chew and tear stuff up. We provide various toys of wood and leather, etc. Ours love to tear cardboard.  " A busy beak is a happy beak ".